# How can I use multiple SCSS files in Symfony?

Tags: symfony, sass, symfony-assetmapper

I'm using Symfony 6.4 with [SassBundle](https://symfony.com/bundles/SassBundle/current/index.html#usage).

I have these files:

```
assets/
  -- images/
  -- styles/
       -- app.scss
       -- homepage.scss
  -- typescript/
       -- app.ts
```

The content of `app.scss`:

```scss
$test-color: blue;

h1 {
  color: $test-color;
}
```

The content of `homepage.scss`:

```scss
$real-color: red;

h1 {
  color: $real-color;
}
```

In my homepage (`templates/home/index.html.twig`) I have the following Twig code:

```html
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block stylesheets %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('styles/homepage.scss') }}" />
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>HELLO</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

`base.html.twig` is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>{% block title %}Welcome!{% endblock %}</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns=%22http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%22 viewBox=%220 0 128 128%22><text y=%221.2em%22 font-size=%2296%22>⚫️</text></svg>">
        {% block javascripts %}
            {{ importmap('app') }}
        {% endblock %}

        {% block stylesheets %}
        {% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block body %}{% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

My `app.ts` (entrypoint):

```js
@import '../styles/app.scss'
```

I use these commands:

```bash
php bin/console sass:build
php bin/console typescript:build
symfony server:start -d
```

The `app.scss` gets compiled correctly, however, the `homepage.scss` file does not. There is a `homepage.css` file being created (in `public/assets/styles`) by `php bin/console asset-map:compile` but it's the exact same as `homepage.scss`. **The SassBundle does not translate the SCSS of any other file than `app.scss`.**

That's not what you can read on the documentation: https://symfony.com/bundles/SassBundle/current/index.html#usage

Am I doing something wrong here?

I tried adding the import of `homepage.scss` in the TypeScript entrypoint, but it doesn't change a thing, the SCSS doesn't get translated.

Comment: What if you were to import homepage.scss into app.scss as a partial? Rename homepage.scss to _homepage.scss and add `@import "homepage"` to the top of app.scss.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell the bundle which files are "root stylesheets", so it can automatically translate the requests.

In your configuration for the bundle, add the following:

```yaml
symfonycasts_sass:
  root_sass:
    - 'assets/styles/app.scss'
    - 'assets/styles/homepage.scss'
```

Or, if you use PHP configuration files:

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

return static function (
    Symfony\Config\SymfonycastsSassConfig $config
) {
    $config->rootSass(
        [
            '%kernel.project_dir%/assets/styles/app.scss',
            '%kernel.project_dir%/assets/styles/homepage.scss'
        ]
    );
};
```